# JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'geometries' of undefined or null reference when importing 3D models into a three.js viewport

Tags: javascript

I am trying to import my own 3D models into a three.js viewport but I keep getting this error:

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property
>   'geometries' of undefined or null reference

My code:

```
            <html>
            <head>
                <title>My first Three.js app</title>
                <style>
                    body {
                        margin: 0;
                    }

                    canvas {
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 100%;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
                <script>
                    // Our Javascript will go here.

                    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
                    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
                    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

                    var json = THREE.JSONLoader("teapot.js"); // I Think this loads the model
                    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
                    var result = loader.parse(json, texturePath);
                    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(result.geometry, result.materials);

                    scene.add(mesh);

                    camera.position.z = 5;

                    function render() {
                        requestAnimationFrame(render);

                        cube.rotation.x += 0.1;
                        cube.rotation.y += 0.1;

                        renderer.render(scene, camera);
                    }
                    render();
                </script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're loading it wrong, when using the loader, first you declare the loader as such:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
```

Then you tell the loader to load your model, since this takes a while, you attach a function to handle adding it to the scene AFTER the loading is done

```
loader.load('path_to_model', function (geometry) {
    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        //whatever material properties you want to use
    });

    // create a mesh with models geometry and material
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
        geometry,
        material
    );
    scene.add(mesh);
});
```

That should do the trick

Comment: 0x800a03f6 - JavaScript runtime error: Invalid character

Now I'm getting this. Am I miss using the models or the code. When I run it, all I see is a black canvas. What's happening.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code / model, could you make a fiddle so i can look into it?